# Layer 'meta-python' depends on version >= 12 of layer 'core'

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I get a strange error. I tried to download the latest version of meta-python on openembedded but nothing changes

> ERROR: Layer 'meta-python' depends on version >= 12 of layer 'core',
> but version 11 is currently enabled in your configuration. Check that
> you are using the correct matching versions/branches of these two
> layers.

MY BBLAYERS
/home/user/poky/meta 
/home/user/poky/meta-poky 
/home/user/poky/meta-yocto-bsp 
/home/user/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe 
/home/user/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking 
/home/user/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia 
/home/user/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python 
/home/user/poky/meta-raspberrypi \

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`core` layer is in `poky/meta`, so you probably have rocko/sumo/thud/warrior (version 11) branch checked out and not dunfell/gatesgarth (version 12). Check out the same branch in all of your layers.